# childfragment does not work when i click the button

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create a memory game, at the first page when I click on the play button it shows the categories and I used fragments. When I click on a button to go to another fragment it doesn't work.

*Mainactivity.java*

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ImageView imageViewA = findViewById(R.id.play_title);
        imageViewA.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                FragmentPlay fragA = new FragmentPlay();
                transaction.add(R.id.fragmentContainer_main, fragA);
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                transaction.commit();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

*FragmentPlay.java*

```
public class FragmentPlay extends Fragment {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_play,container,false);
        return rootView;
    }

    public void addFragB(){
        FragmentManager childFragMan=getChildFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction childFragTrans = childFragMan.beginTransaction();
        FragmentAnimal fragmentAnimal = new FragmentAnimal();
        childFragTrans.add(R.id.fragmentContainer_main2, fragmentAnimal);
        childFragTrans.addToBackStack(null);
        childFragTrans.commit();
    }
}
```

*FragmentAnimal.java*

```
public class FragmentAnimal extends Fragment {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_animal,container,false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Comment: post your xml code for this activity and if your fragment has xml code post that too pleeeasssseee

Comment: Also, posting logcat is useful

Comment: From what you have provided so far I can only surmise that you have yet to manually place a fragment container in your Activity XML code.